# Jquery-ui autocompolete default text

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jquery-ui autocomplete text box and i want to set a default text for the text box and when the text box get focus i want to remove it.

- How do i set the initial text for the text box?
- Ho do i remove the text on focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it:

1. set the default text of the autocomplete using the value attribute
2. the only way that i damaged to use the focus event is like this:

   `$("SELECTOR").autocomplete({
      .... 
   }).focus( function(event, ui) {

      ...... 
   });`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   focus: function(event, ui) { $(".selector").val('');}
})
```

Comment: tnx, but how do i set the initial text?

Comment: yeah in your text box set as value